# Basic understanding of loops in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm having a hard time understanding how to loop jQuery, I think my problem is I think in a PHP manner.

Lets say I've got this very simple example.

HTML:

```
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:relative">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").animate({height:300},"slow");
$("div").animate({width:300},"slow");
$("div").animate({height:100},"slow");
$("div").animate({width:100},"slow");
});
```

Se it [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/FjQJV/)

If i understood correctly, I would have to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) *

But I cant figure out how to make it work.

**NOTE:** This is only an example, I'm interested more in the approach you would take, rather the actual looping.

Thanks in advance, please ask if any clarification is needed!

*I'm not necessarily looking for an answer with .each(), any approach you take is fine for the learning purposes.

Comment: Are you trying to loop the animation forever, or just a set number of times?

Comment: @Thomas, sorry fot the delay (I'm not getting notifications for some reason). I actually hadn't thought about it, Nick Craver helped me out with an infinite one, I you've got the time, that that can be set a number of times, would be much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a function you can kick off as the last animation's callback, like this:

```
$(function(){
    function loop() {
      $("div").animate({height:300},"slow")
              .animate({width:300 },"slow")
              .animate({height:100},"slow")
              .animate({width:100 },"slow", loop);
    }
    loop();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FjQJV/2/).

Comment: @Mike - nope, it doesn't queue but 4 animations at a time :)

Comment: Heh, yeah I went and tried it in jsfiddle, then deleted my post :)

Comment: @Mike I though @Nick was going crazy :)

Answer (score 1):

Stealing Nick's code so we can expand it to terminate after a number of iterations.

```
$(function(){
  function loop(n) {
    if(n > 0)
    {
      $("div").animate({height:300},"slow")
          .animate({width:300 },"slow")
          .animate({height:100},"slow")
          .animate({width:100},"slow")
          .animate({width:100 },"slow", loop(n-1));
    }
  }
  loop(5);
});
```

The second `.animate({width:100},"slow"` is not a typo.  I don't understand why but the shrinking width animation doesn't occur without it.

Comment: thank you for taking the time! Works like a charm! If anyone is interested, here is the working example http://www.jsfiddle.net/FjQJV/8/ Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery (almost always) automatically applies the methods you run on every element returned by the selector.

In your example, every div on the page would be animated.

Also, jQuery is chainable, meaning you can remove a lot of duplicate code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div")
  .animate({height:300},"slow")
  .animate({width:300},"slow")
  .animate({height:100},"slow")
  .animate({width:100},"slow");
});
```

Also know that you can animate more than one property at a time with the .animate() method.  Depending on your desired effect, you could combine the properties being animated.

Comment: Ok, sorry but I'm lost, I can't see what this has to do with the loop  - not saying it doesn't :)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by loop.  (Hint: I didn't think you were talking about looping the animation, which apparently you were.)  :)

Comment: Yes, I think you did, very sorry if I did not express myself correctly, thank you for you answer anyway! BTW what I ment was basically answered by Nick Craver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340003/basic-understanding-of-loops-in-jquery/4340038#4340038 Thanks again.